# How to align a view to the center of a GridLayout cell?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridlayout

How do I align ImageViews to the center of each cell of a GridLayout?

What I'm aiming for:

[image: What I'm aiming for]

What I have now:

[image: What I have now]

this is the layout code of one of the ImageViews

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView00"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        app:layout_column="0"
        app:layout_gravity="center"
        app:layout_row="0" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `scaleType`:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView00"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    app:layout_column="0"
    app:layout_gravity="center"
    app:layout_row="0" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView00"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        app:layout_column="0"
        app:layout_gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" // <---- add this
        app:layout_row="0" />
```